# Can you upload objects to an s3 bucket using only cognito client credentials flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a service that runs on a server. It is using the client credentials flow to receive an access token, which it then uses to access endpoints in an API gateway.

This service also needs to upload a variable number of objects to an S3 bucket. Is there any way to grant access to upload objects to an S3 bucket to Cognito client?

We'd prefer not to track a separate access key and secret key for an IAM User. A solution we've thought of is for the service to identify what objects it must upload, pass the object keys to an endpoint, the endpoint generates pre-signed URLs and returns them but that doesn't seem great either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [definition](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-client-credentials-flow/#what-is-a-client-credentials-flow-in-oauth-20)

```
The Client Credentials flow is a server to server flow. There is no user authentication involved in the process. In fact there is no user at all, the resulting access tokens will not contain a user, but will instead contain the Client ID as subject
```

Hence, there is no direct way of granting access to upload objects to S3. The approach that you have mentioned using `pre-signed URLs` is the only way forward.